# Are both of these patches crabgrass?

Tags: identification, crabgrass

I have what appears to be, two types of crabgrass growing.  One with thicker, longer, higher blades. Another with skinnier, shorter blades.

I have seen the "[real crabgrass video](http://web.extension.uiuc.edu/podcasts/gc/201107_849.html)", but still not able to determine if this is truly crabgrass or not.

[image]

Comment: it would make identification a **lot** easier if you could pull out both samples, then take close-up photos of them...

Comment: @Mike Perry: Yes, it would be helpful if, as a general rule, close-ups of the plant's roots/ stem/ leaves/ flower could be provided with *every* identification request; very often, it is impossible to identify a plant without at least three of these. This is probably something we need to discuss on meta..

Answer (score 3):

The below PDF (direct link) should greatly help you identify what weed(s) you're seeing in your lawn:

- [Turfgrass & Weeds - University of Missouri Extension](http://extension.missouri.edu/explorepdf/agguides/pests/ipm1009.pdf)

Comment: Good info.  Thanks for the link.  I'll use that as a go to reference before submitting to this site.